Python polars write / read csv handling of linebreaks (eol)
I want to read in mockup data that contains a linebreak (eol) char.
Here I utilize the faker package to simulate some data.
I initialize a polars.DataFrame and write it to .csv. When I later on try to read the csv
(see below), I receive an error, which indicates that the match between the column-name, the dtype (schema_overrides) and the data does not match.
My best gues is, that the error is due to the linebreak / eol in the line field. If I comment out the generation of the address field it runs through smoothly. Now how does one best handle strings with linebreaks? I thought this should be catched via the quote_char (default =") and the quoting_style in df.write_csv (link)
Error

pydf = PyDataFrame.read_csv(
polars.exceptions.ComputeError: could not parse "Edwards, Duncan and Moore" as dtype date at column 'Date_of_birth' (column number
5)
The current offset in the file is 309563 bytes.

Code Producing the error
# Reading in throws an error
df_throws = pl.read_csv("mockme_up.csv", schema_overrides=dtypes, separator=";")

MRE Data
import polars as pl
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()
# Erstellung der Mockup-Daten unter Verwendung von Faker
N = int(1e4)
data = {
    "Name": [fake.name() for _ in range(N)],
    "Address": [fake.address() for _ in range(N)],
    "Email": [fake.email() for _ in range(N)],
    "Phonenumber": [fake.phone_number() for _ in range(N)],
    "Date_of_birth": [
        fake.date_of_birth(minimum_age=18, maximum_age=90) for _ in range(N)
    ],
    "Company": [fake.company() for _ in range(N)],
    "Job": [fake.job() for _ in range(N)],
    "IBAN": [fake.iban() for _ in range(N)],
    "Creditcard": [fake.credit_card_number() for _ in range(N)],
    "Creation_date": [fake.date() for _ in range(N)],
}

dtypes = {
    "Name": pl.Utf8,
    "Address": pl.Utf8,
    "Email": pl.Utf8,
    "Phonenumber": pl.Utf8,
    "Date_of_birth": pl.Date,
    "Company": pl.Utf8,
    "Job": pl.Utf8,
    "IBAN": pl.Utf8,
    "Creditcard": pl.Int64,
    "Creation_date": pl.Date,
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
df.write_csv("mockme_up.csv", separator=";", quote_style="non_numeric")
print("=" * 50)
print(f"Succeful created mockup data of shape {df.shape=}")
print("=" * 50)

Update / Solution
This is now tracked as github issue: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19078
As a workaround passing n_threads=1 to read_csv() will fix the issue

I believe this to be a bug in the CSV reader.

I made a bug report: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/19078.

As a workaround for now you can pass n_threads=1 to read_csv and it will correctly read it. It's a bug in the procedure that splits the CSV into parallel chunks, I believe.

Thank you very much. I am really always stunned how fast the community around pola.rs is

Added the solution to the post for more visibility. as well as the log to the github issue
